# Automate Bitcoin Wallet Creation

Tags: wallet, development

I spent several hours looking for an API, or a documentation that wouldn't be too much complex but this single thing which I was thinking would be a natural question for anyone who wanted to get started with Bitcoin programming doesn't seem to be very documented.

I'm looking for a way to automatically create a Bitcoin wallet online, I want to create an experience similar to this : http://www.bitcoinbymobile.com/ ("Get Started" -> "I don't have a bitcoin Wallet"). They create a bitcoin wallet for the user directly online and give him a bitcoin address : that's exactly what I would like to achieve. However I can't find any documentation on it.

My ultimate goal is to create a wallet online for the user and to let him put money in this wallet using his local currency and his credit card. But considering what I've seen so far, bitcoin exchange automation seems to be a great deal at this time.

To clarify, my whole question is : do you know any good (and ideally easy) way to programmatically create a bitcoin wallet and generate an adresse on a website AND (I realize it's a different question) to fund this account with a credit card. I find that this is the part of using bitcoins that is really missing.

We can't expect people to use bitcoins for retail commerce if there is not an easy way to create a wallet and to fund it rapidly. For now, what I have understood is that people have to create a wallet either by downloading the program or by creating it on a website and then, they have to have to find an other good website to buy bitcoins. The actual system seems to be more oriented to financials who don't mind to do it than to the average customer who will very rarely complicate his life like this.

Comment: -1 for not searching at all. It is clearly stated on bitcoin wiki.

Comment: Try to search for a bitcoin API assuming that you're new to bitcoin and you'll see that it's not that obvious. I have even visited the link that you posted to me twice during my research but as I wrote, I was asking for a standard solution that a more experimented programmer would use in my case. I find your down vote a bit harsh. I don't find it this clear and obvious if I have to be honest.
Thank you for your answer anyway, I'm grateful for that. Now I know where to investigate.

Comment: @user6376 https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_(JSON-RPC) This is the first result in google for me. As for a downvote being harsh: A downvote means 'This question does not show any research effort;' Frankly, I agree.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use JSONRPC interface used by bitcoin daemon.

See this: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_(JSON-RPC)
or specific PHP example: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/PHP_developer_intro